# Is it possible to make save button (not save as button) to save document in specific path?

Tags: vba, excel, save, save-as

I want to make save button for my validation program in VBA excel.

A save button will save the file in a  spesicic path and rename automaticallyby the status of document (Clean or Error).

If the document has been save when the document still error, the file will be named error.xlsm

But, when i fix the error of document. The document will be named clean.xlsm.
It’s annoying me to delete the first file (error.xlsm) manually.

Is it possible to make save button save (not save as button) to save document in specific path without using save as?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\" & Sheets("C").Range("G23").Text & ".xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:=vbNullString, WriteResPassword:=vbNullString, _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

*note: `Sheets("C").Range("G23").Text` contains status of document (clean or error with if formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim fName As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("C").Range("G23").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="D:\" & fName & ".xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:=vbNullString, WriteResPassword:=vbNullString, _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
On Error Resume Next
Select Case fName
    Case "Error"
        Kill "D:\Clean.xlsm"
    Case "Clean"
        Kill "D:\Error.xlsm"
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: i have been tried it, sir.. but, there is still 2 file, (clean and error). i want if the file is clean, the error file that had been save before, erased automatically..

Comment: The code first saves the file with the file new file name as per the string available in G23 and delete the other file. I have tried the code and it ran without an issue.

Comment: thank you sir, i know the problem.. i just erased ActiveWorkbook.Close. and it works!!! thank youuuuu

Comment: @arifulromadhon - Please remember upvoting/accepting the answer, if you deem it appropriate.

Comment: @arifulromadhon  Since you were using ActiveWorkbook.Close in your original code, I assumed that you were running this code from another workbook and that's why I didn't remove it. But Glad you figured it out yourself. :)